# What does 'fist bump' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I have seen *fist bump* mentioned in some books, and would like to know what it means.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. A simple web search for "fist bump" turns up many explanations and photographs of the gesture, e.g. *[fist bump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fist_bump)*. If you have a question about the phrase suitable for [linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour), I suggest you edit the original question, or if you are not familiar with StackExchange, to visit the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: This is general reference i.e you can easily search this on web.

Comment: This site is not for these "easy" questions that can be searched easily. Also, take a look at the English Language Learners site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's when two people are bumping their fists together.

> A fist bump (also called dap, pound, fist pound, bro fist, spudding,
> fo' knucks, box, Bust, pound dogg, props, Bones, respect knuckles, or
> bumping the rock) is a gesture similar in meaning to a handshake or
> high five.
>
> A fist bump can also be a symbol of giving respect. It can
> be followed by various other hand and body gestures and may be part of
> a dap greeting. It is commonly used in baseball as a form of
> celebration with teammates, and with opposition players at the end of
> a game.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fist_bump